# How to create a folder in home directory(ubuntu16.04) using GCP start up script at time of GCP VM creation?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, startupscript

Here is what I am doing:
`gcloud compute instances create example-instance \ --image-family $image \ --image-project $projectID \ --machine-type $type_machine \ --metadata startup-script='#!/bin/bash mkdir -p ~/test'`

This look super simple. The instance is created no test folder is created in home directory. I checked the VM logs I can't find anything.
So this means we can not create a folder in home directory with GCP VM startup script?
Or is there any thing I am missing?

1. Checked the VM logs but didnt find anything.
2. Was manually able to create folder in home directory after the VM is created.

Answer (score 0):

According to your script and to the logs, your folder is correctly created in the home folder.

But the home folder of which user?? You are using a path shortcut ~/ but for who?

In the documentation, it's mentioned that the startup script is launched as ["root" user.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/linux) When you, user "Learning", ssh to the VM, a /home/learning/ home directory is created.

And it's obviously not the same as the root user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how gcloud executes the *start script*, but a reasonable assumption is that it runs it using `sh`.

Your startup script starts with a comment character. Therefore, the whole line is treated as a comment and nothing gets executed. The `#!` would make sense as a pseudo comment as the first line in a script file (which is different from your case), but even then, the `mkdir` would have to be in the **subsequent** line.

However, even removing the #! would not help in your example, for the following reason:

If you run `bash foo bar baz`, bash executes the command `foo` as bash-script and passes to it the parameters `bar` and `baz`. In your case, the command is `mkdir`, and this is not a bash script, but a binary executable. You would get the error message

```
mkdir: cannot execute binary file
```

Therefore, the solution would be to use the `-c` option and write

```
/usr/bin/bash -c 'mkdir -p ~/test'
```

as "start script". The `-c` tells bash to interpret the following argument as a statement to be executed.

BTW: If gcloud really understands the start-script argument as `sh` command, you don't need bash at all and can simply use

```
mkdir -p $HOME/test
```

Since it is most likely that the start script is executed with the working directory set to what glcoud considers your home, you should be able to do just a

```
mkdir -p test
```